# Run more than one application in veins

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

How to run 2 or more apps in veins node as sender and 2 or more apps at RSU as receiver and queue each app packets?

I don’t want to use more than three layers, app, mac and phys.

I tried this, but does not work.

```
*.node[*].appl.applType  = "TraCIDemo11p"
*.node[*].appl.headerLength = 80 bit
*.node[*].appl.sendBeacons = false
*.node[*].appl.dataOnSch = false
*.node[*].appl.beaconInterval = 1s


*.node[*].appl[1].applType = "TraCIDemo11p"
*.node[*].appl.headerLength = 80 bit
*.node[*].appl.sendBeacons = false
*.node[*].appl.dataOnSch = false
*.node[*].appl.beaconInterval = 1s
```